# Chaining select with page load/onclick event in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to chain two select drop-downs with the onclick event but with little success. This is what I've managed to achieve so far.

This is my code so far:

**form.php**

```
$("#dept").click(function () {
    var dept = $("#dept").val();
    var dataString = 'dept=' + dept
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
           $('select.moduleCode').html();
        }
    });
});

Department    
<select name="dept" id="dept">
<option value="<?php echo $loggedin_id; ?>">
<?php echo $_SESSION[$thename]; ?></option>
<option>---------------------------------</option>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ts_dept WHERE id<>:id";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':id' => $loggedin_id ) );
$rows = $stm->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row) 
{
  echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">
  '.$row['dept'].'
  </option>';
};
?>
</select>

<p>

Module Code
<select name="moduleCode" id="moduleCode">
<option>---------------------------------</option>
</select>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
require_once("../resources/php/connection.php");

$dept_id = $_POST["dept"];

$sql = "SELECT id FROM ts_module WHERE id=:id";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':id' => $dept_id ) );
$rows = $stm->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row) 
{
    echo '<option>'.$row['id'].'</option>';
}
?>
```

I am trying to fill the **option**'s of the **moduleCode** drop down with values based on the selection made in the **dept** dropdown (this event should be initiated on page load as well. But despite the user making a selection in the **dept** drop down, nothing is refreshed in the **moduleCode** dropdown. What changes do I need to make to my code to sort this problem out?

Comment: You are doing nothing with your return in `$('select.moduleCode').html();`, unless the intended purpose of the AJAX is to clear it.  The `success: function (html) {` gives you a local variable of `html`, which you should do something with ^^

Comment: Hi @Jon, thanks for the reply. I'm not to sure how to fill the select moduleCode dropdown with all of the options in the process.php. What would you recommend?

Comment: `$('select.moduleCode').html(html);` ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax call doesn't do anything with the response from your php, try:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
       $('#moduleCode').html(html);
    }
});
```

I would also change `$("#dept").click(` with `$("#dept").change(` so it will work for users without a mouse, and so it only loads the new data when it changes, not just when clicked on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer John. I think the problem now lies with process.php - the values of the select field do not appear to be showing, I'm not sure how to fix his - I cannot "drop down" the menu

Comment: Your PHP, from the look of it, will only ever have 1 result, and only if the submitted 'id' exists in the database, and then it outputs that 'id' as an option?  When you submit to the PHP page directly (so you can see the output given), is it the expected output?

Comment: @methuselah you also want to make sure your js in the beginning of the page has `$(document).ready(function(){` before and `});` after it so that the DOM is fully loaded. (Until now, I've assumed that you've had it as such)

Comment: Yay it works now :-). One last question. On page load there is already a pre-selected value in the dept value. How can I initialize the AJAX call on page load for this pre-selected value and have it run concurrently alongside `.change` event

Comment: If it's already preloaded via the PHP creating the page, why not populate it when the page is created?  No need to create an ajax call for 'default' content.